# Attribute error: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, authentication, attributeerror

I'm quite new to python and django. Here is my little project and this is the error message I get when I'm trying to log in as a user to my account. I have tried all the solutions which I gained by searching. Please if you know the solution explain it to me quite simply.

My log in view

```py
def login_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST, request=request)
    if form.is_valid:
        user = form.user_cache
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('accounts:user-home')
else:
    form = AuthenticationForm()
return render(request, 'login.html', {'form':form})\
```

My forms.py

```py
# import form class from django
from django.forms import ModelForm
  
# import GeeksModel from models.py
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  
# create a ModelForm
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    # specify the name of model to use
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = [
            'user',
        ]

class UsernameChangeForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', ]
```

My login.html

```html
<h2>Log In</h2>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
<p>Don't have an account yet? <a href="{% url 'accounts:register' %}">Register</a></p>
```

Comment: what about changing `user = form.user_cache` to `user = form.save()`?

Comment: @mohammad-mirsafaei  Actually I got this solved by changing user = form.user_cache to username = form.cleaned_data.get('username') and password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')